# Error: Failed to create local cache ('.httr-oauth') in R on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, oauth, httr

I have recently installed R on Ubuntu and tried to run a R script on the same. 
Although the same script works on windows properly I'm getting error write httr-oauth file.

My codes are as follows

```
require(RGoogleAnalytics)
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
require(googlesheets)
library(rjson)
long_end_date <- Sys.Date() - days(day(Sys.Date()))
long_start_date <- long_end_date -90
end_date <- Sys.Date()
start_date <- Sys.Date()-2

token <- Auth("XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

I am getting the following error

```
Use a local file ('.httr-oauth'), to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1
Error: Failed to create local cache ('.httr-oauth')
```

I initially though it's a file permission error, and provided write and edit access to all the user. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: May be you could look [that](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR/issues/84) ...